# How to give a unique id to multiple audio elements in order to play them with Jquery

Tags: html, jquery, coldfusion, html5-audio

I'm working on a audio player in coldfusion + jQuery,
I achieved to set a SRC for each and it's corresponding.

My problem now is i can't play the audio src cause when i .play() with jQuery it "tries" i guess to play everything with the same id.

I need to set a new unique id but i don't understand how to do it, i tried with jQuery but with no success.

Here an exemple :

```js
$('.btn_player').click(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
console.log('button audio player clicked');
var idtemp = $(this).attr("id");
        var idtemp = idtemp.split("_");
        var idtemp = idtemp[1];
        console.log(idtemp);
document.getElementsByClassName("audio")[0].play();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<td>
  <a class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn_player" id="player">foo
    <audio id="audio">
      <src="./assets/vocab/#formation_id#/5/#voc_cat_id#/word_#voc_id#_#formation_id#_5.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
    </audio>
    <i class="fad fa-play"></i>
  </a>
</td>

<td>
  <a class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn_player" id="player">foo2
    <audio id="audio">
      <src="./assets/vocab/#formation_id#/8/#voc_cat_id#/word_#voc_id#_#formation_id#_8.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
    </audio>
    <i class="fad fa-play"></i>
  </a>
</td>

<td>
  <a class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn_player" id="player">foo3
    <audio id="audio">
      <src="./assets/vocab/#formation_id#/10/#voc_cat_id#/word_#voc_id#_#formation_id#_10.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
    </audio>
    <i class="fad fa-play"></i>
  </a>
</td>

<td>
  <a class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn_player" id="player">foo4
    <audio id="audio">
      <src="./assets/vocab/#formation_id#/15/#voc_cat_id#/word_#voc_id#_#formation_id#_15.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
    </audio>
    <i class="fad fa-play"></i>
  </a>
</td>
```

i'm looking for a solution with jQuery or Coldfusion.

Comment: Please note you can't have multiple elements with the same id.

Comment: noted, but i'm looking for a way to set an ID to multiple elements with jQuery or Coldfusion, thank you for the reminder tho !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how your logic works around the number after `vocab/#formation_id#/` (`#formation_id#/5/`, `#formation_id#/8/`, etc.), you can

1. put them in an array
2. loop the array and use the index and the numbers in your element IDs.

This way, you will have unique IDs for all your anchor and audio elements

```
<cfset nums = [ 5, 8, 10, 15 ] />

<cfloop array="#nums#" item="item" index="index">
    <cfset idPrefix = "-#item#-#index#" />

    <td>
        <a class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn_player" id="player-#idPrefix#">
            foo#index#
            <audio id="audio-#idPrefix#"><src="./assets/vocab/#formation_id#/#item#/#voc_cat_id#/word_#voc_id#_#formation_id#_#item#.mp3" type="audio/mp3"></audio>
            <i class="fad fa-play"></i>
        </a>
    </td>
</cfloop>
```